# WPF System.ExecutionEngineException when adding PageFunction.Return handler

Tags: c#, wpf

I have simple window in wpf application

```
<Window ... >
     <Frame  Name="contentFrame" Margin="0 60 0 0" Source="ContentPage.xaml" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
</Window>
```

and simple page function named SettingsPage (public partial class SettingsPage : PageFunction in code-behind) . At some point i execute code in window code-behind

```
    SettingsPage settingsPage = new SettingsPage();
    settingsPage.Return += settingsPage_Return;
    contentFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(settingsPage);
```

where

```
public void settingsPage_Return(object sender, ReturnEventArgs<bool> e)
    {
        String test="test";
    }
```

In page function i execute code

```
OnReturn(false);
```

and getting System.ExecutionEngineException. 
I need to catch SettingsPage close event and i maked it when created delegate inside SettingsPage and manually raised it, 
but i dont understand why standart WPF functionality not working.
Anyone know why WPF raise error in this situation?

Comment: you have a typo on setting Margin on Frame. Should be `Margin="0,60,0,0"`. Don´t know if this is only wrong in your question or also in your code

Comment: That's the nastiest possible way for a .NET program to crash.  Try another machine.

Answer (score 1):

This may because your page is garbage collected. The cause of System.ExecutionEngineException is usually so. [Related MSDN definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.executionengineexception.aspx) says:

> In some cases, an application that targets the .NET Framework may
>   throw an ExecutionEngineException exception during garbage collection
>   when an application or the system on which it is running is under a
>   heavy load. As a workaround, you can disable concurrent garbage
>   collection by modifying the application's configuration file. For more
>   information, see How to: Disable Concurrent Garbage Collection.

[Disabling concurrent garbage collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at1stbec%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) may be a way to find out if it is really so.

Comment: OnReturn(false); in page fucntion code-behind executed without error.

Comment: Don't understand why PageFunction.Return event not raising.